# Get UserManager from Hangfire Job

Tags: c#, owin, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to run background jobs, as part of one of those jobs I want to be able to send emails.  I would like to use the mechanism I have in the rest of my application namely using UserManager.SendMailAsync.    The difficulty I have is being able to create a reference to the OwinContext or UserManager inside a hangfire tasks.

Code like:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
```

Will just fail with an error.  As per the hangfire documentation I have create an authorization filter which can successfully attach to the OwinContext, however I cannot seem to be find a way to do this inside a hangfire task.

I've also tried the following:

```
 var context = new OwinContext();
            var aaa = context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

I can never get a reference to the user manager

Answer (score 3):

```
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(
    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Then do what you want on this `userManager`.

**NOTE**

Be Careful when use this trick, you must make sure your code won't take different UserManager instance to update(user). for example:

```
/* Wrong demonstration */

var userManagerA = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var userFormA = userManagerA.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
userFormA.EmailConfirmed = false;
// some stuff ...

var userManagerB = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
// Will product a Exception from EntityFramework
userManagerB.Update(userFormA);
```